# spinning loader until async page load in asp.net webform

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Simply, I want to show a spinning div on the page load until the page complete an async task that bring data from a database. While you can see a lot of samples on how to show a spinning loader during page load, no one specify the case of async page load where all examples are failing.

To simulate the case, I did the following:

Create a new Web application (Web Forms), and in the default page, just `await Task.Delay(6000);` to simulate my database call and then `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "HideLoader", "HideLoader();", true);` to hide the spinning div. (or supposedly, use JavaScript event like document ready, window load, document load...). **In page async load, all JavaScript event will fire after the async task!!!**

[image]

I Put         `<div id="loader" class="loader center"></div>`
in the site master.

add a script to hide the spinning div when the page is fully loaded. I used all possible events to see which one is hitting first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('document ready: ' + GenerateDate());
});

$(window).on('load', function () {
    console.log('window load: ' + GenerateDate());
});
$(document).on('load', function () {
    console.log('document load: ' + GenerateDate());
});

document.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        document.querySelector(
            "body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector(
            "#loader").style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log('document.onreadystatechange: ' + document.readyState + ': setting body to hidden and loader to visible : ' + GenerateDate());
    } else {
        document.querySelector(
            "body").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.querySelector(
            "#loader").style.display = "none";
        console.log('document.onreadystatechange: ' + document.readyState + ': setting body visible : ' + GenerateDate());

    }
};
function HideLoader() {
    document.querySelector(
        "#loader").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(
        "body").style.visibility = "visible";
    console.log('HideLoader from code behind: setting loader to none and body to visible ' + GenerateDate());
}
function GenerateDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = addZero(d.getHours(), 2);
    var m = addZero(d.getMinutes(), 2);
    var s = addZero(d.getSeconds(), 2);
    var ms = addZero(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);
    var fullDate = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ":" + ms;
    return fullDate;
}
function addZero(x, n) {
    while (x.toString().length < n) {
        x = "0" + x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Finally, the spinning div is not showing at all. it shows an hide immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well, since this IS ON page load?

Then setup the page to show the spinner by default.

Then let page load, then after page is loaded, you call/run your longer running task.

Lets have a simple example.

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdLongRun" 
            runat="server" Text="run long code load grid" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="cmdLongRun_Click"
            style="display:none"/>

        <br />
        <div id="myspin" runat="server" style="display:normal">
            <img src="Content/wait2.gif" /><br />
        </div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="table" Width="40%" >
        </asp:GridView>
```

When the page loads, we will load up a gridview. But, lets assume that the process takes say a few seconds.

So, page will load - the spinner as above will display.

(we could have 2 div - one around the grid view, but our gridview has no data - so it don't display and we don't care - but this I suppose could in theory be 2 divs).

So, we let the page load and THEN using script, click on our above button.

So, our code to load this up is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then

        ' first page load - so after page loads, run a start up script that clicks 
        ' a button on the page to run the code behind long runnnig task.
        Dim strJava As String = "$('#cmdLongRun').click();"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "My Load script", strJava, True)

    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub cmdLongRun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
            FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using

    ' fake a long delay
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) ' 3 seond delay
    myspin.Style("Display") = "none"   ' hide spinner

End Sub
```

Now I assumed jQuery (for the button click + selector). So, we let page load (by default display spinner).

Then page loads, and we injected that button click to click on our button.

Long run button code runs (while spinner is displayed). When long running code is done that same code hides spinner. Page cycle completes, and our gird displays.

[image]

## edit: You can also do this without a button click and post-back.

You can use jQuery to trigger after page load. Like this:

```
            $(document).ready(loadmytextbox())

            function loadmytextbox() {
                if (IsPostBack() != true) {
                   $('#NotesEdit').hide();
                   $('#noteswait').show();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'IssueEdit.aspx/GetNotes',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: OnGotText,
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
                }

                function OnGotText(response) {


                    var tbox = document.getElementById('txtNotes_HtmlEditorExtender_ExtenderContentEditable');
                    var buf = response.d;
                    tbox.innerHTML = buf;
                    buf = "";
                    // tbox.innerHTML = 'back from service';
                    $('#NotesEdit').show();
                    $('#noteswait').hide();
                }
            }
```

So, in above, noteswait is a spinner. On document.Ready() we call our js code to load up some data into a text box, but I show a spinner while this occurs (noteswait.Show).

Comment: can you change it to async Task instead of regular and see if this works?

Comment: Sure, in place of injecting a button click, you can also simple call your javascript stub. I mean, on page load, the spinner displays by default and will be in full view. So, you can in place of that js button click, simple call your js code - only when the js code is done, say even making a web service call, upon return from that web service call, it can simple use $('#MySpinnerDiv').hide() - and the spinner will hide. Or as noted, you can have a button click (and post back) in js code - the server side code can then hide the spinner in code behind - either way this will work fine.

Comment: See my 2nd example and edit above - it on browser "ready" runs some js code. That js code displays a spinner, does a web service call - and when complete, it hides spinner. so in 2nd example, we don't inject a button click + post back, but again are free to display spinner after web page loads - calls some code that takes time, and then hides the spinner. So, you can do this either way (have a another post-back (button click) to run code behind - code behind hides spinner. or, on page load, run js code - web service call and again shows + hides spinner (this works even without ost-back)